# Waiting for dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory to come up; Action client not connected: dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory

Tags: ros, moveit, arm-controller, follow-joint-trajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, when i try to connect moveit to my gazebo simulation i get the following error:

```
[ WARN] [1633040618.377249905]: Waiting for dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1633040624.377429395]: Action client not connected: dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory
[ERROR] [1633040629.027678746]: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (30s)
```

i am using noetic ros, ubuntu 18.04, gazebo and moveit.

Mi archivo **controllers.yaml** luce del siguiente modo:

```
joint_state_controller:
type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - name: dof_fit
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - Joint_1
      - Joint_2
      - ...
  - name: hand_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    parallel: true
    joints:
      - Gripper_Idol_Gear_Joint
      - Gripper_Servo_Gear_Joint
```

my **kimo_control.yaml** file:

```
dof_fit:
    # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
    joint_state_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 50
    
    # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
    Joint_1_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: Joint_1
      pid: {p: 60.0, i: 40.0, d: 0.0}
    Joint_2_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: Joint_2
      pid: {p: 80.0, i: 60.0, d: 0.0}
    Joint_3_position_controller:
  #..........
```

a part of the error:

```
[ INFO] [1633040607.368356602]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner::PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[ INFO] [1633040607.369259001]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[ INFO] [1633040607.369275481]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[ WARN] [1633040612.377062495]: Waiting for dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ WARN] [1633040618.377249905]: Waiting for dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1633040624.377429395]: Action client not connected: dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory
[ERROR] [1633040629.027678746]: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (30s)
[ INFO] [1633040629.028283349]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[ WARN] [1633040629.392726935]: Waiting for hand_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ WARN] [1633040635.392889117]: Waiting for hand_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1633040641.393057390]: Action client not connected: hand_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ INFO] [1633040641.403387237]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1633040641.412451398]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[ INFO] [1633040641.412487078]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
```

This error happens when I try to connect my gazebo simulation with moveit_rviz.launch and start to do movement planning.

Is the choice of controllers in controllers.yaml correct?

```
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
```

What controllers should I choose to control a joint: type: effort_controllers / JointPositionController?

rosnode list:

```
/arm_controller_spawner
/dof_fit/controller_spawner
/gazebo
/gazebo_gui
/move_group
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/rviz_iudc_desktop_pc_18608_6360793226529266128
```

rostopic list:

```
/attached_collision_object
/clock
/collision_object
/dof_fit/Gripper_Idol_Gear_Joint_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Gripper_Idol_Gear_Joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Gripper_Idol_Gear_Joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Gripper_Idol_Gear_Joint_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Gripper_Servo_Gear_Joint_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Gripper_Servo_Gear_Joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Gripper_Servo_Gear_Joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Gripper_Servo_Gear_Joint_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_1_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_1_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_2_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_2_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_2_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_2_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_3_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_3_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_3_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_3_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_4_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_4_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_4_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_4_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_5_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_5_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_5_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_5_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/Joint_6_position_controller/command
/dof_fit/Joint_6_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/dof_fit/Joint_6_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/dof_fit/Joint_6_position_controller/state
/dof_fit/joint_states
/execute_trajectory/cancel
/execute_trajectory/feedback
/execute_trajectory/goal
/execute_trajectory/result
/execute_trajectory/status
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/performance_metrics
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points
/joint_states
/move_group/cancel
/move_group/display_contacts
/move_group/display_cost_sources
/move_group/display_grasp_markers
/move_group/display_planned_path
/move_group/feedback
/move_group/filtered_cloud
/move_group/goal
/move_group/monitored_planning_scene
/move_group/motion_plan_request
/move_group/plan_execution/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/plan_execution/parameter_updates
/move_group/planning_pipelines/ompl/ompl/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/planning_pipelines/ompl/ompl/parameter_updates
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/move_group/result
/move_group/sense_for_plan/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/sense_for_plan/parameter_updates
/move_group/status
/move_group/trajectory_execution/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/trajectory_execution/parameter_updates
/pickup/cancel
/pickup/feedback
/pickup/goal
/pickup/result
/pickup/status
/place/cancel
/place/feedback
/place/goal
/place/result
/place/status
/planning_scene
/planning_scene_world
/recognized_object_array
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/rviz_iudc_desktop_pc_18608_6360793226529266128/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/rviz_iudc_desktop_pc_18608_6360793226529266128/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/feedback
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update_full
/sequence_move_group/cancel
/sequence_move_group/feedback
/sequence_move_group/goal
/sequence_move_group/result
/sequence_move_group/status
/tf
/tf_static
/trajectory_execution_event
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387763/waiting-for-dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory-to-come-up;-action-client-not-connected:-dof_fit/follow_joint_trajectory/) by [Arnolvalencia1](https://answers.ros.org/users/71811/arnolvalencia1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-04**:
Please edit your description to show us the output of `rosnode list` and `rostopic list`. You edit using the "edit" button at the end of your description.

**Comment by [Arnolvalencia1](https://answers.ros.org/users/71811/arnolvalencia1/) on 2021-10-04**:
arm_controller appears when a `rosnode list` is written but when it performs `rostopic list` the services are not connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have any topic name that ends with `.../follow_joint_trajectory/goal`? If not, you have not started the Action Server.

Did you use the same controller name in gazebo config and in MoveIt config? See 2nd answer to #q296694.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arnolvalencia1](https://answers.ros.org/users/71811/arnolvalencia1/) on 2021-10-04**:
the solution was to follow the steps described in the second answer and add to my gazebo simulation the controller like this:

```
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" ns="/dof_fit" args="joint_state_controller
                                            arm_controller
                                            Joint_1_position_controller
                                            Joint_2_position_controller
                                            ......"/>
```

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-05**:
Glad you figured it out - I've never found good docs for this ros_control stuff.

**Comment by [Arnolvalencia1](https://answers.ros.org/users/71811/arnolvalencia1/) on 2021-10-05**:
I found an interesting template that solves many ros_control problems, I will work on it, I share the link:

https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-06**:
Thanks for the link. I'll take a look at it.